# Force https://www.domain to https://domain

Tags: .htaccess, magento, ssl, https

I just switched our Magento website from http://www.domain.com to https://www.domain.com in the exitement than now everything would be fine...

But now all old http://www.domain.com -url´s is now showing: NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID, insecure domain...

https://domain.com and https://domain.com/etc/etc works fine...

I guess I have to force all traffic somehow...

But how ?

Comment: Is the domain name on your certificate with www or without?

Comment: I thought that the certificate was both with and without but apparently it is only without.

Answer (score 0):

The certificate is read as part of the SSL handshake, and this happens **before the request** is even sent to the server. During this handshake, your browser sees that you've requested "www.something" and the cert says it's only for "something" (without the www.), and so the browser STOPs right there and gives you that error. There is **nothing** you can do through htaccess to prevent that error. You need to buy a new cert or change all your links to only point to the non-www hostname (but this won't prevent people getting the error when you go to the www hostname).

Comment: its fine that the user is being redirected, but then it also have to work. 

What are others doing when migrating from http:// to https:// where the user previously could come from both http://domain.com and http://www.domain.com without any problems ?

Comment: @TheDenster the user can't be redirected without seeing the error and accepting the security exception. What other people do is they buy a cert that is for both www and without.

Comment: I will contact my supplier asap then... have to be fixed :)

Comment: @JonLin Denster in his question says that `https://www` works fine although his cert is without `www`. How does it happen?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I have now corrected the question... I meant 

https://domain.com and https://domain.com/etc/etc works fine...

...of course...